# Why isn't this C# regular expression working?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I tried to write an expression to validate the following pattern:

> digit[0-9] at 1 time exactly
>   "dot"
>   digit[0-9] 1-2 times
>   "dot"
>   digit[0-9] 1-3 times
>   "dot"
>   digit[0-9] 1-3 times or “hyphen”

For example these are legal numbers:

```
1.10.23.5
1.10.23.-
```

these aren't:

```
10.10.23.5
1.254.25.3
```

I used RegexBuddy to write the next pattern:

```
[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.-
```

In RegexBuddy all seems perfect but in my code I am getting true about illegal numbers (like 10.1.1.1)

I wrote the next method for validating this pattern:

```
 public static bool IsVaildEc(string ec)
        {
            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ec))
                    return false;
                string pattern = @"[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.-";
                Regex check = new Regex(pattern);
                return check.IsMatch(ec);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //logger
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont get it, so before the first dot there is 1 digit [0-9] but you say that 10.X.X.X is valid?

Comment: No. the first number must be 1 digit exactly

Comment: why do you put \??, It should be without it

Comment: Protip: `\d` is a shorter version of `[0-9]`.

Comment: @AnnArbor87: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx), `.` is a wildcard for any single character in regular expressions. The OP wants literally a dot, a `.`, hence he or she has to escape it with `\`.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know, I thought it was '?'

Comment: @AnnArbor87: `?` indicates that the *preceding*  subexpression may appear zero or one time. i.e. `.` => any character; `.?` => any character or no character at all.

Comment: Protip 2: This is a shorter version of your entire regex: `\d\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}\.(\d{1,3}|-)`

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm beginner in this world - Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Not in .NET! That regex would also match `².³.۴.-` because `\d` is Unicode-aware.

Comment: Another question - Why RegexBuddy behavior is different from Regex behavior? In RegexBuddy my patten seems to be good...

Comment: @Ofir: Some methods or tools that evaluate regular expressions assume implicitly that the regular expression is meant to match the whole input string (apparently RegexBuddy belongs to this group), while others (the .NET API you are using) do not.

Comment: @Kendall - From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#DigitCharacter): *"`\d` ... is equivalent to the `\p{Nd}` regular expression pattern, which includes the standard decimal digits 0-9 as well as the decimal digits of a number of other character sets."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You regex isn't anchored to the start and end of the string, therefore it also matches a substring (e. g. `0.1.1.1` in the string `10.1.1.1`).

As you can see, RegexBuddy matches a substring in the first "illegal" number. It correctly fails to match the second number because the three digits in the second octet can't be matched at all:

[image: RegexBuddy Screenshot]

```
string pattern = @"^(?:[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.-)$";
```

will fix that problem.

Then, your regex is needlessly complicated. The following does the same but simpler:

```
string pattern = @"^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}|-)$";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
@"^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.-"
```

you are not starting from the beggining of the text

Comment: Careful, the scope of your anchor is incorrect because of the unbounded alternation in the middle of the regex. Also, you're missing an end-of-string anchor.

Answer (score 0):

If you match against the "10.1.1.1" the "0.1.1.1" part of your string would be a correct number and therefor return true.

Matching against

```
@"^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.-"
```

with the `^` sign at the beginning means that you want to match from the beginning.

Comment: This also returns `True` on `123.1.1.-` which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `^` char in the start of the regex.

Try this regex:

```
^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.-
```

This [C# Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) can be handy

Comment: This is the same answer as two others before you and it contains the same mistake as them...